# Display images from Structure

Tags: structure, entry-type, image

I have a Structure section (`galeriesPhotos`) with two Entry Types:

- **Albums** - the categories on the index.html page
- **Photos** - the the actual gallery on the `entry.html`

I'm trying to display the images related to the "Albums" on `entry.html` like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('galeriesPhotos').getEntryType('Photos') %}

{% for image in entries %}
  <img src="{{ image.getUrl }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing happens. I get a blank page without any errors. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think the for loop is incorrect, try changing {% for image in entries %} to {% for entry in entries %} and then change the img src to {{ entry.image.first().url }} Also if you switch on dev mode in the config it will help debug your templates.

Comment: Just tried that and it's not working

Comment: It actually gives only the path to where the images are (<img src="http://www.example.com/gallery/2014/friday/") instead of the actual images that are uploaded in structure... Your suggestions give an error. Sorry

Comment: Impossible to access an attribute ("url") on a NULL variable ("")

Comment: OK sorry and thanks I entered the correct fieldHandle. It shows one image twice instead of all images that are related to this page. I guess I miss a relatedTo setting.

Comment: Have a look at the Templating section on this page - http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields

Comment: Thanks. I was looking way too far. This made it: `code`{% for asset in entry.entryFieldHandle %}
        <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
    {% endfor %}`code`

Comment: Well done. Suggest you post your working code as an answer and tidy up the comments.

Answer (score 2):

In the example code above, the query is retrieving a list of Entries and setting it to the variable `entries`.  Then, you are trying to loop through those Entries and treat them like they are a list of Assets.

As noted in the comments, this was complicating the situation.

It appears that, on the `entry.html` page, the `entry` variable was already available, as Craft makes that `entry` variable to all individual entry pages in Sections that have URLs.

This makes accessing the Assets field on that page as simple as accessing a field, rather than needing to create a separate query to find the data.  From the comments above, the solution was to just access the appropriate Assets field on the Entry Page template and loop through them:

```
{% for asset in entry.entryFieldHandle %}
    <img src="{{ asset.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```